# How to call different method at initialization level if same component is used multiple time?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am new in Angular. I have a common component which I wanted to use in different angular material tabs. I just wanted to call different methods in ngOnInit().

If we wanted to load different content with same component, we can do it with `<ng-content>` directive at template level. But how to execute different methods on initialization level if same component used at multiple times?

This is template code:

```
<mat-tab-group class="col-lg-12 row">
  <mat-tab label="tab1">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-tabs></app-tabs>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="tab2">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-tabs></app-tabs>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

This is ts code:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.wantToCallOnTab1();
  this.wantToCallOnTab2();
}
```

So the method `this.wantToCallOnTab1();` I wanted to call on tab1 and `this.wantToCallOnTab2();` wanted to call on tab2.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it'll be hard to do in `ngOnInit()`, but you could use `Input()` to differentiate the two tabs and call your methods based on what `Input()` it recieved. You'll have to do this in `ngAfterViewInit` though, since `Input()`s are only set after this lifecycle.

Comment: @MikeS. `@Input` values are available in `ngOnInit`, no need to wait until the view is initialized. Another possibility, however, would be to have your components register in a service, that way you'd know if an instance already exists.

Comment: @WillAlexander You're right, maybe I was thinking about `@ViewChild()`. Silly me :)